# codeigniter function parameter cant get public variable

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

```
. . . .

  public $counts_per_page = 15;

  public function getNames($user_id, $count = $this->counts_per_page){
    //do stuff
  }

. . . .
```

I am getting an error on second parameter as it doesnt allow me to do this...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
```

how can i solve this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the php manual:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

You can set it to null or some other default instead and then check for that within the function.